# How to add agent's presentation which is in another to the main?

Tags: anylogic

Hi I have an agent called B in side my agent A. Agent A has been added to the `main`. I have a plot inside agent B and I want to show that in my `main`. So I am calling `currentTurbine.plot.setLocation(plotNode);` in `on startup` field in `main` but this will not add the plot onto my main. Any reason for this? And how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it differently:

1. In the plot properties, ensure to tick "show on upper level"
2. select AgentB that is embedded in Agent A
3. in the properties of AgentB presentation, click the "shhow presentation" button (if it is grayed out, that is fine)

You will now see AgentB's presentation alongside AgentA's presentation on Main

Comment: Now I can see the Agent B name alongside Agent A on  main. But I cannot see the presentation of Agent B in main

Comment: edit the original question to share more details (or open a new one=

Comment: Strange thing I did and now it is showing. for the Agent B presentation on the main I enabled Scale is - Defined explicitly then it started showing on my main. but when running my main view scale was changed. So I adgust the scaling of Agent B as same as the Agent A and selected the Scale is - Automatically calculated. Then problem solved. Thank you very much for your support :)

Comment: yeah, all these animation settings are always "cumulative", so it is easy to mess it up as a user :)